# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll

Tags: windows-phone-8, invalidoperationexception, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am making an app which records sounds.
When clicking the mike button it is supposed to move to a new page.
When I add a save button in the application bar of the new page and then run it, it throws this exception

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
```

If I don't add the save button it works fine

Comment: Are you following a guide? or you made the application by yourself.

Comment: Please specify the Mike Button and the save button and what do they do on click. Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for Update 4 for visual studio 2012.Its size is about 2gb download and install the update and you're done

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39305